# Trying to singin user with service account, for serverside app

Tags: python, node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I have made one service account at my console.google.com for all other settings I have used
everything is set up according
To this
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

added client Id in mydomain.com

My below code working nice but
What to do for nodejs?

```
creds =      
service_account.Credentials.fro.m_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
delegated_credentials = creds.with_subject('ga@mydomain.com')
```

Now how to do it in node?